# Wordpress default Attachment Post Type, to be listed in various plugins like other post types

Tags: post, types, edit, attachment, display

How to make default wordpress attachment post type to be listed and available to various plugins like posts, pages, or any other custom post type? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To make the default WordPress attachment post type available and listed in various plugins like posts, pages, or any other custom post type, you can use the show_in_rest parameter for the attachment post type. This parameter allows you to enable or disable the REST API for a particular post type, making it available for use in various plugins and features within WordPress.

Comment: Thak you so much for response. Problem is, I am not the programer. How someone like me can do what you suggest using some plugin or to paste some code into functions file?

Comment: Chat GPT give me this solution

function enable_attachment_post_source( $args, $post_type ) {
    if ( 'attachment' === $post_type ) {
        $args['public'] = true;
        $args['hierarchical'] = true;
    }
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'enable_attachment_post_source', 10, 2 );


but it wont work.